# Replace only the date part

Tags: sql-server, date

This question may be duplicate sorry for it,As I could not able to find any solution in web till now so am Posting this

I need to create a SQL server functions where I need to replace only the date part from the actual date ..

For example if the actual date is `01/10/2016` means I need to update the actual date to  `15/10/2016` the date part alone is replaced from 01 to 15 I need to achieve this, please help me in solving this as am very new to SQL SERVER

Comment: Why not use DATEADD function

Comment: you just want to replace 01 to 15, or in other words you are adding 14days to your date?

Comment: can you please post any example code snippet @JaydipJ

Comment: @Pirate yes only the date need to be changed not the month and years

Comment: what if yours date is 02, then you don't want to replace that?

Comment: no not like that I gave you a example that's it

Comment: Which dates do you actually want to update? All days in October 2016 to the current day? Or are you even trying to change the day in other months? If so be aware that some days don't exist (e.g. September 31).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @actual_due_date INT = 5;
DECLARE @invoice_date DATETIME = '20161210';
DECLARE @due_date DATETIME;

SET @due_date=DATEADD(DAY,@actual_due_date-DATEPART(DAY,@invoice_date),@invoice_date);

SELECT @due_date;
```

This prints out

```
2016-12-05 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Not working it adds the date not replacing it, I don't need to update it in table rather i need to store and see it in a variable

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav More correctly, it adds **to** the date. Its effect is replacing all datetime's whose date-part equals 2016-10-01, with 2016-10-15. The reason my answer adds days to the date you wish to replace, is that it's the most efficient way of doing this. Other solutions cast the date to string first, and fiddle with strings. That's less efficient than simply adding the difference in dates.

Comment: SET replace_date='20161015' does not be a DATETIME and also static one it is BIGINT

Comment: I need to replace the date part alone from the give date, I don't want to be updated in tables, I need to Store it in a variable

Comment: IF my given date is 2016/10/15 and the calculated BIGINT value is 5, here I need to replace the 5 in place of 15 so it will look like 2016/10/5

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav Perhaps I misunderstood the question... You are not seeking to update dates in a table? You just need to replace a variable date? I'll add that to my answer just in case that is what you want.

Comment: Now you got the question ?

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav I think I did, updated answer, hope it's what you expected this time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125904/discussion-between-m-balajivaishnav-and-tt).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it:

```
DECLARE @oldDate DATETIME = '2016-10-17 10:29:22'
DECLARE @replacingDate DATE = '2016-10-15'
DECLARE @newDate DATETIME
SET @newDate = CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, @replacingDate)+' '+ LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(time, @oldDate)), 8))
SELECT @newDate

--UPDATE TableA
--SET FieldX = CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, @replacingDate)+' '+ LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(time, @oldDate)), 8))
--WHERE SomeCondition
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, what you really try to achieve, but you could try this:

```
DECLARE  @OtherDate DATETIME = {ts'2016-02-05 12:00:00'}; --Some day in February, 12 o'clock

DECLARE @actualDate DATETIME = GETDATE(); --current day and time


--This comes back with the other date, but the actual time
SELECT CAST(CAST(@OtherDate AS date) AS datetime) + CAST(CAST(@actualDate AS time) AS datetime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the purpose, why you are replacing it.

Here is one way:

```
Declare @date date = '01/10/2016'

Select Replace(Convert(varchar(20), @date, 101), '01/', '15/') AS ReplacedDate
-- 15/10/2016
```